# Generic entity configuration class in EF Core 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to create a generic configuration class for my entities but i'm stuck.

I have an abstract class called EntityBase:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

And many other classes that inherit from EntityBase, in which i have to configure the DateTime properties in each one with the same code. This way:

```
void EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.HasIndex(e => e.TenantId);
        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
              .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
              .HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()");

        // Other specific configurations here
    }
```

I would like to be able to call somthing like: builder.ConfigureBase() and avoid the code duplication. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this purely for setting a default value or is this scenario rather like "automatically set those values on insert /edit"?

Comment: Just to configure the TenantId as an Index and setting the default value for the CreatedOn property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several way you can accomplish the goal. For instance, since you seem to be using `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` classes, you could create a base generic configuration class with `virtual void Configure` method and let your concrete configuration classes inherit from it, override the `Configure` method and call `base.Configure` before doing their specific adjustments.

But let say you want to be able to exactly call `builder.ConfigureBase()`. To allow that syntax, you can simply move the common code to a custom generic extension method like this:

```
public static class EntityBaseConfiguration
{
    public static void ConfigureBase<TEntity>(this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
        where TEntity : EntityBase
    {
        builder.HasIndex(e => e.TenantId);
        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
              .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
              .HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()");

    }
}
```

with sample usage:

```
void IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntity> builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureBase();
    // Other specific configurations here
}
```